# How to delete a kind in Google cloud datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the `Cloud Datastore Admin` console, I can only delete all entities of a certain `kind`. I am wondering how to delete the kind along with all its entities as well.

I am using `datastore emulator` as the local dev server.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After you delete all the entities of a kind, the kind will no longer appear in the Cloud Datastore Admin console.  I don't recall if it is immediate.  It might take 24 hours or so.

Comment: almost immediate.

Comment: Is there any official document around this?