# How change Kind names or Delete Kind at Google Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I want to change names of Kind in Datastore or Delete some Kind, 
Someone knows about that?

Comment: Say what you tried and how it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think both questions have already been answered here on Stack Overflow:

- Changing name of a kind:
  [How to change google cloud datastore kind name ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48818864/how-to-change-google-cloud-datastore-kind-name)
- Delete some kind: 
  [How to delete a kind in Google cloud datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576533/how-to-delete-a-kind-in-google-cloud-datastore)

In summary:

- You cannot rename a kind in Datastore, you can write some code to automate the process of moving the entities to a new kind.
- Using Datastore Admin in Google Cloud Console you can delete all the entities of a kind. After some time (depending on the number of entities deleted, usually minutes) the kind will be deleted too.

Good luck!